# Como receber a resposta de 2 threads e armazenar num metodo?

Tags: java, tcpclient

O problema é o seguinte: possuo um servidor que recebe 2 jogadores (cada um numa thread) utilizando TCP/IP. 
Na run de cada thread informam a jogada (pedra, papel ou tesoura). 
Eu tenho uma classe "Jogada", que possui o metodo "avalieJogada", onde ela deve receber a jogadada desses 2 jogadores e comparar quem ganhou.

A ideia é que o construtor da classe jogada receba a resposta dos dois clientes, e envie ambas para o metodo "avalieJogada", mas nao faço ideia de como fazer isso.

Ou caso haja uma solução mais simples...

Tentei colocar 2 jogadores na mesma thread, mas nao sei como colocar mais de um elemento numa thread...

Obrigado pela paciencia!

SERVIDOR:

```
public void startServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        servidor = new ServerSocket(6789);
        System.out.println("Servidor iniciado!");
        while (true) {
            // aceita a conexao de um cliente
            cliente = servidor.accept();
            // precisa salvar a msg do cliente em jogada1
            BufferedReader leitura = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cliente.getInputStream()));
            // recebe a jogada do jogador
            String s = leitura.readLine();
            // recebe as 2 jogadas de maneira assincrona
            // envia a jogada aos respectivos metodos call
            Future<String> jogada1 = pool.submit(new Jogada(s));
            Future<String> jogada2 = pool.submit(new Jogada(s));

            pool.shutdown();

            try {
                pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                // esses dois tambem nao sao exibidos
                String jogadaFeita1 = jogada1.get();
                String jogadaFeita2 = jogada2.get();

                System.out.println("Jogada1: " + jogadaFeita1);
                System.out.println("Jogada2: " + jogadaFeita2);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

    }
```

Classe JOGADA, que implementa CALLABLE:

```
public class Jogada implements Callable<String>{

    String jogada;

// onde recebe a jogada
    public Jogada(String jogada) {
        this.jogada = jogada;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Jogador escolheu: " + jogada);

        return jogada;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na minha opinião, o mais simples é implementar a interface `Callable<T>` no lugar de `Runnable` e utilizar da class `Future` do Java.

No exemplo abaixo, estou utilizando o `Executors` para iniciar um *pool* de 2 *threads*.

A classe `JogadaInput` é basicamente a sua classe `Jogada`, porém, implementando a interface `Callable<String>` que permite rodar em paralelo e retorna um `Future<String>`.

Observe que o código bloqueia o paralelismo no momento do `.get()` do objeto `Future`, portanto, o `.get()` só deve ser feito após submeter as duas *threads* ao *pool*.

```java
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        //Recebe as duas jogadas de maneira assíncrona
        Future<String> jogada1 = executorService.submit(new JogadaInput());
        Future<String> jogada2 = executorService.submit(new JogadaInput());

        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

            //Obtém as jogadas feitas na outra thread.
            String jogadaFeita1 = jogada1.get();
            String jogadaFeita2 = jogada2.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
```

Comment: Ola, obrigado pela ajuda! Uma duvida. Como posso colocar cada jogada em seus respectivos future String? Exemplo: a jogada do jogador 1 em "jogada1" e a jogada do jogador 2 em "jogada2". Do jeito que tá, ele recebe uma entrada e exibe essa mesma entrada em ambos os gets. Modifiquei o meu codigo no topico